# how to show product info after image in bigger zoom levels

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, shopping-cart

In shopping cart details page product image is defined using code below. Its proportions should preserved.

For bigger zoom levels image hides start of text after it.

How to render this page properly in all zoom levels?

For unknow reason div #productinfo starts at left side but it shoult start after image.
I tried to add display:inline-block to every div but this does not have any effect.
jquery, jquery ui, fancybox and pikachoose are used.

html:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 1%">
            <a href="#" class="details-picture">
                <img src="/Thumb?product=1308318&amp;size=198" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
<div id="productinfo">
 <div>
            Price <span id="Price">
                1.73
            </span>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.details-picture {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: thin ridge #BBBBBB;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 20px 15px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 198px;
}
.details-picture img {
    border-width: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 198px;
    max-width: 198px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to those inline attributes on the top-level `div`. The combination of `float: left` and `width: 30%` causes the issue you were experiencing.

```
<div class="productimage">
    <a href="#" class="details-picture">
        <img src="/Thumb?product=1308318&amp;size=198" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="productinfo">
    <div>
        Price <span id="Price">1.73</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTJrS/)

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the issue. I removed productimage div at all. This div is not nessecary, styling anchor element is sufficient isn't it ?

Comment: @Andrus Yes, styling an anchor element is technically sufficient. If you are going to have multiple of these sets of images and info, just make sure you use classes instead of IDs. Also, if that is the case, I'd probably recommend wrapping each set in something like `<div class="product">...</div>` for clarity and separation.